# Calculating approximation factor of a TSP algorithm

Tags: algorithms, approximation, traveling-salesman

The literature that I have reviewed shows examples of calculations of known approximation algorithms such as the Christofides' algorithm for the TSP. However, I have not been able to find information regarding the calculation of the approximation factor of an algorithm that has a loop inside as the one in the example below. Is this possible? Does someone know a book or article that does this? Should I try another approach?

For more context, I'm trying to prove an approximation factor for an algorithm for the TSP that starts with a partition of the graph in k connected components (by removing certain arcs of the graph). Then, the algorithm iterates, bringing together the optimal matching of connected components in each iteration (for the matching we use all of the arcs of the original graph that belong to a vertex in the connected component). We do this until the connected components are all connected, and with this we build the tour.

Comment: I think this question is too broad.  Any community votes?  "approximation factor of an algorithm that has a loop inside" seems too broad to me -- I see no reason to expect a single answer or single technique for that entire category of algorithms.  I think it's better to ask about a specific, concrete problem, e.g., approximation factor for your particular algorithm (except if you build a random algorithm without already having a proof in mind, it's unlikely it will have a good provable approximation factor, so that might not be useful).

Comment: @D.W. I have just changed the title to account for the ambiguity. But my question is meant to be general because I want to know if there are approximation algorithms that use that kind of inside loop. Also, I edited it with more details on the sketch algorithm. Thanks for the feedback and please respond if more changes are necessary!

Comment: I appreciate the desire to be general.  That's great!  Keep it up.  In my opinion, this particular formulation seems too general to be answerable in a few paragraphs.  "algorithm that has a loop inside" captures almost every algorithm.  There is no short answer for "calculation of approximation factor of algorithms" - one could write a book on the topic.  What you are asking, in your general question, is almost equivalent to that.  Perhaps your best bet is to read a textbook on approximation algorithms?